# Can't get a straight line connector in Visio

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010

When I try to draw a connection between the two points highlighted in the pink circles, Visio gives me the stupid right-angled line as shown. Why is it doing this? I just want a straight line between the two points!

I have tried turning off all the settings in the Snap & Glue dialog. Dynamic Grid, AutoConnect, AutoSize are all off. Changing the line to "Straight Connector" does nothing. Is there some other "clever" feature I should turn off?

[image]

I could use the line tool rather than the connector tool but this wouldn't help when I did need a bend in my line, because I still get the problem of not being able to get the start and end points to be where I want them.

[image]

The line is apparently connected, although it doesn't move when box2 is moved:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This checkbox must be enabled !
[image]

Comment: Doesn't help, sorry

Answer (score 1):

But in my case it works fine with these settings !!!!!!!
[image: for these settings in works]

Comment: Yes, that works for me in a new document but not in my current document. There must be some other setting that is causing the line to end in a completely different place to where I told it to.

Comment: I use Visio about 18 years, as i know **Snap & Glue Window** is exclusive place where you can find all connection settings !

Comment: I'm not making it up! I finally found some screen recording software that didn't need installation (my work computer is locked down) - see edited post.

Comment: At your gif these shapes situated very nearly, what behavior when shapes are far (distance more than shape size) ?

Comment: If I move the second shape much further away, exactly the same thing happens - I get exactly the same size and shape of line as before.The end of the line is apparently connected to the second box but invisibly, and the line doesn't move with the second box. See pic in original post.

Comment: Your rectangles have connection points ?

Comment: Yes, I get the red square showing that a connection has been made. I just tried dragging some rectangles from the Shapes panel to see if they were somehow better, but got the same result.
What I could do is use the "Universal connector" from the Shapes panel instead of using the Connector tool from the toolbar. This seems to work!